# Why norm of matrix is differ from norm of array in Python Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, norm

I am trying to use numpy to get norm of a vector. By using array or matrix, I got different results.

If a = np.array([3,4]), the result is correct: n1=7, n2= 5, ninf=4.

If a = np.matrix('3 4') the result is incorrect: n1=4, n2=5, ninf=7

Could anyone tell me what's wrong in following code? Thanks a lot.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix('3 4')

n1 = np.linalg.norm(a,ord=1)
n2 = np.linalg.norm(a,ord=2)
ninf = np.linalg.norm(a,ord = np.inf)

print(repr(n1)) # should be 7
print(repr(n2)) # should be 5
print(repr(ninf)) # should be 4
```

Comment: Did you check the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)? They explain this behavior.

Comment: that's coherent with the [online doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html), arrays and matrix are not treated the same way.

Comment: Yes. I think Iinalg.norm works for array, and matrix is subclass of array, so linalg.norm should get the same result if I feed it a matrix. Interestingly, the result for norm order 1 and order inf just got swapped. It's weird that linalg can only handle array, but not matrix.

Comment: I get the same answers for `np.matrix([3,4])` and `np.array([[3,4]])`.

Comment: Thanks for help. My result is different. I tried Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 with numpy 1.11.1 and got the same problem. Still no idea what happened... :(